# If my users are stored in another database, should I duplicate them in my service that uses SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, microservices

If my users are stored in some other database, but I am building posts in my SQL database, should I create another table `users`?

If I did, I would be duplicating all of my users and would have to make sure this stays in sync with the other database, but on the other hand, my posts tables could save space by referring to fk instead of full id string each time.

What is the recommendation? Create another table `users` or just pass in the user ids to query?

Comment: Use the same database for both. You can use different schemas to have a "logical boundary" if you want. Or use something like Prostrgres' foreign data wrappers to access other databases.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what the *other* database is being used for?

I have a student management system that interacts with various security systems around the college and we don't want the door system connecting to any other systems so we store the users in their database, which updates only new records every 10 minutes during the day.

If our management database goes down (or the security database) they aren't dependent on each other to continue operating.

Comment: @stickybit While I would strongly prefer to use the same database, I am unable to do that in this case due to some requirements. Foreign data wrappers look great, but unfortunately it is missing the connection that I need.

Comment: Not sure I understand the options you're considering. I think there are 3:
- store user IDs in your table, and when you want to show information about the posts, retrieve user info from your other database
- duplicate user data into your posts database
- use foreign keys and joins between two databases, which you say is impossible for "requirements". 
Is that a correct summary?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Yes, and to give an example for option 1, posts would have `author: "abc123"` where "abc123" is a user id that doesn't currently exist in this database.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a service that stores and provides information about users then other services that need that information should communicate with the User service to get it.  That is, presumably, the reason the User service exists in the first place.

Depending on the volatility of the users list and requirements for changes there to be respected in the Posts service you might consider some short-term caching in the Posts service, but I certainly wouldn't persist another copy of the user list there.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 obvious solutions.

The simplest, cleanest and fastest is to use foreign keys and joins between your "posts" database and your "users" database. In this case, when you show a list of posts, you can get both the post and user data in a single query, and there's no need to keep things up to date.

The next option is to store a copy of the user data alongside your posts. This leads to entertaining failure modes - data in the user database may get out of sync. However, this is a fairly common strategy when using 3rd party authentication systems (e.g. logging on with your Google/Facebook/Github/Stack Exchange credentials). The way to make this work is to minimize the amount of data you duplicate, and have it be safe if it's out of date. For instance, a user's display name is probably okay; current bank account balance is probably not.

The final option is to store the primary key for users in your posts database, and to retrieve the user data at run time. This is less likely to lead to bugs with data getting out of sync, but it can cause performance problems - retrieving user details for 1000 posts one by one is obviously much slower than retrieving everything through a joined query.

The choice then is "do I have a service which combines post and user data and my UI retrieves everything from that service, or do I let the UI retrieve posts, and then users for each post". That's mostly down to the application usage, and whether you can use asynchronous calls to retrieve user information. If at all possible (assuming you're building a web application), the simplest option might be to return the posts and user IDs and use Ajax requests to retrieve the user data as needed.

The [CQRS approach](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (common to microservice architectures) provides some structure for this.